# Read json value after Uin8Array conversion to string

Tags: javascript, json

Have Uint8Array which is converted to string via

```
const str = String.fromCharCode(...resp[0][0]);
```

Console.log produce

```
str:{"contentType":"image/jpeg","name":"fileUpload","filename":"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\bd767cae/1927905d3ca2ad2f56136aec0ccba000d024f88b.jpeg","originalName":"WP_20150311_004.jpg"}
```

Obviously cannot just do `console.log(str.filename)`
in order to see filename value so help appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can console.log(str.filename)

Comment: Well, at least I got an error indicating that path slashes were the problem. By changing filename value to string without slashes, the issue was resolved. However, I solved this by splitting str and reading array indexes separately.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Decode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/decode) the `Uint8Array` which holds the *valid JSON data*
2. [Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it to a native JS data type

```js
// '{"msg":"hello world"}'
const u8Arr = new Uint8Array([123, 34, 109, 115, 103, 34, 58, 34, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 34, 125]);
const json = new TextDecoder().decode(u8Arr);
const data = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(data.msg); // "hello world"
```

Comment: Seems that my json is kind of valid, but path slashes give problems so how to get filename value out from the above str ?